# pydriveのアクセストークンについて

Tags: python, google-api, pydrive

現在、pydriveでリフレッシュトークンの取得方法が分からず困っています。
分かる方いましたら、解決方法を伝授してください。
(id:''とf['']は値を空にしていますが、実行時には値を入れています。）

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
pydrive.auth.RefreshError: Access token refresh failed: invalid_grant: Bad Request
```

**ソースコード:**

```
# GoogleDrive関連ライブラリ------------------------------
import os
import pprint

# 必要なライブラリのインポート
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

# OAuth認証を行う
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.CommandLineAuth()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
# -----------------------------------------------------

# GoogleDriveからexcelファイルをダウンロード
f = drive.CreateFile({'id': ''})
f.GetContentFile(os.path.join(f['']))

# Googleドライブにアップロード --------------------------------------------
f = drive.CreateFile(
    {
        #"parents": [{"id": ""}],
        'id':''
    }
)
f.SetContentFile('sample.xlsx')

f.Upload()
# -------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: pydriveの[document](https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/)を見ると、2種類のAuthorization processが使用できるようです。1つはGoogleからダウンロードした`client_secrets.json`を直接読み込んで使用する。もう一つは、`settings.yaml`を使用する方法です。前者の場合、毎回scopeの認証を行う必要があるようです。後者の場合、`save_credentials_file`へファイル名を指定すると、そこへリフレッシュトークンが記録されて、次回以降、このリフレッシュトークンを使用してアクセストークンが取得されるようです。この質問では、どちらの方法をお使いでしょうか。質問へ問題を再現するための詳細なフローを追記すると、解決策を見出しやすくなるかと思いました。

Comment: @Tanaike 後者のやり方を参考に解決できました。ありがとうございます。